# How can I disable "Do Not Disturb" mode for NotifyOSD?

Tags: thunderbird, pidgin

I use a number of programs in fullscreen mode during the workday. When I do this, Ubuntu assumes I don't want to be disturbed by notifications, so I am not alerted when people attempt to contact me over IM, or when I get email.

I would like to always see on screen notifications, whether I'm using an application fullscreen, watching a movie, or whatever. How do I disable 'Do Not Disturb' mode?

Comment: with fullscreen apps it may be possible,  but I'm  not sure what you mean by movies.  Watching  videos in fullscreen? i don't  recall notify osd being disabled if video is playing

Comment: It depends on where (and if) the blocking takes place. If no one answered yet I will hand you a script to find out. ( am on mobile atm )

Comment: Jacob, I would like to try your script. These are the programs I know suppress OSD notifications for me: Geany, Terminal. I'm sure there are others.